# IIS - Upload size limit

Tags: iis

I use a sharpoint on premise installation with IIS for web. I setup two type of authentification. NTLM authentification (seen as Windows auth for IIS) and ADFS authentification (seen as anonymous auth for IIS).
The issue is on upload size limit.
If I use NTLM account, there is no issue.
If I use ADFS account, the upload size limit is 52428800 bytes
I try to modify the maxAllowedContentLength but without success. Any idea? It's just like anonymous account has another limitation in IIS.

Comment: You can refer to the steps in the link to set maxAllowedContentLength: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/

Comment: As I explain, modification was done and works for standard account but not for guest.